width: inherit/100% of a child
I want to put a side bar on top of an image, with the same width as the image.  Neither width: inherit|100% work.
CSS
       body {
            display: flex;
        }

        #main-pic {
            width: 40%; 
            height: 700px;
        }

        #main-pic>img {
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;
        } 

        #logo-holder {
            width: inherit; 
            height: 100px;
            background-color: brown;
            position: absolute;
            top: 50%;
        }

HTML
    <div id="main-pic">
        <img src="myFlower.JPG" alt="My Flower">
        <div id="logo-holder"></div>
    </div>

    <div id="main-text">
        <p>This is the part for text</p>
    </div> 

In this example, I use width: inherit, the #logo-holder is a bit longer than the image. I tried width: 100%, it's stretched across browser. Can someone explain and suggest a solution?

You need to assign position: relative to the #main-pic element, so its children could use its relative dimensions properly:


body {
  display: flex;
}

#main-pic {
  width: 40%;
  height: 700px;
  
  /* added */
  position: relative;
}

#main-pic>img {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

#logo-holder {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  background-color: brown;
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
}
<div id="main-pic">
  <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/42/400/800" alt="My Flower">
  <div id="logo-holder"></div>
</div>

<div id="main-text">
  <p>This is the part for text</p>
</div>




This answer is useful, although it doesn't explain that when you position an element absolutely, it is positioned relative to its nearest positioned ancestor, or the body if there is no positioned ancestor. This answer converts #main-pic into a positioned ancestor by adding position: relative – so then your absolutely positioned logo is positioned relative to that. However, while this approach works, I think the semantics explained in my answer are important too, so I’d still recommend using a background image instead.

This works! Thank you. I thought I had tried it, but put position: relative; above width and  height. Does it have any impact?

@Sonia The impact should be very minimal. Unlike position: absolute, it keeps everything like a normal container does but only tells its children to "use my coordinates for relative dimention calculation".

From the name of your image (myflower.jpg) and your description of what you are trying to do, it sounds like you want your sidebar to have some pretty flowers in the background, as a decorative addition to your page.
In that case, because the purpose of the image is style rather than substance, it belongs in your style rules, your CSS. Add a background declaration to your sidebar style rule which references your image of flowers. Your logo image, however, is part of your content rather than being purely aesthetic, so it should remain referenced from your HTML.
This answer explains the same thing using different words.


body {
  display: flex;
  margin: 0;
}

#sidebar {
  width: 40%; 
  height: 700px;
  background: url(http://picsum.photos/id/106/800/1600);
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

#logo {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  border: 3px solid brown;
} 

main {
  padding: 0 1em;
}
<div id="sidebar">
  <img id="logo" src="http://picsum.photos/200">
</div>

<main>
  <p>This is the part for text</p>
</main>




This is not exactly what I want to do. The answer is below. Thank you anyway.
